# Problem in Minify when using HttpContext directly in Asp.Net Core 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, compression, startup, httpcontext

**Startup.cs**

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {

        services.AddWebMarkupMin(
                options =>
                {
                    options.AllowMinificationInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                    options.AllowCompressionInDevelopmentEnvironment = true;
                })
            .AddHtmlMinification(
                options =>
                {
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveRedundantAttributes = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpProtocolFromAttributes = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHttpsProtocolFromAttributes = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.MinifyInlineJsCode = true;
                    options.MinificationSettings.RemoveHtmlComments = true;
                    options.CssMinifierFactory.CreateMinifier();
                    options.JsMinifierFactory.CreateMinifier();
                })
            .AddHttpCompression();

          services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
          services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
            app.UseHsts();
        }

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();
        app.UseStaticFiles();

        //minify
        app.UseWebMarkupMin();

        HttpContextHelper.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());

    }
}
```

**I add HttpContextHelper as follows**

```
public class HttpContextHelper
{
    private static IHttpContextAccessor m_httpContextAccessor;

    public static HttpContext Current => m_httpContextAccessor.HttpContext;

    public static string AppBaseUrl => $"{Current.Request.Scheme}://{Current.Request.Host}{Current.Request.PathBase}";

    internal static void Configure(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        m_httpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
}
```

I have used the `WebMarkupMin` library to compress the `cshtml` files and called it in the `Startup.cs` file.
The problem is that I want to use the `HttpContext` in the project directly anywhere in the classes. When I add `HttpContextHelper` to `Startup.cs`, it gives the following error.

**Error Text**

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'destination')
>
> System.IO.StreamHelpers.ValidateCopyToArgs(Stream source, Stream destination, int bufferSize)
> System.IO.MemoryStream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination, int bufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
> System.IO.Stream.CopyToAsync(Stream destination)
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5.BodyWrapperStreamBase.InternalFinishAsync()
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5.BodyWrapperStreamWithResponseBodyFeature.FinishAsync()
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext
> context, bool useMinification, bool useCompression)
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.InvokeCore(HttpContext
> context, bool useMinification, bool useCompression)
> WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5.WebMarkupMinMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

When this code `HttpContentHelper.Configure(app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>());` And this code `services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();` I delete it, it displays the desired View correctly.

Comment: Have you installed the latest version? [A new release came out 12 days ago](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WebMarkupMin.AspNetCore5/#versions-body-tab). On the other hand, .NET 5 [went out of support in May 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core). Library authors no longer provide fixes for it. The Long Term Support versions of .NET Core are 3.1 (which itself reaches EOL in December) and .NET 6, supported until 2024. Library authors quickly stop supporting versions for unsupported runtimes

Comment: Currently, **.Net5** is used in the project and I cannot upgrade it at the moment. Is there a solution to this problem? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: On application startup you get this error or when some codes are executing? why you are injecting `HttpContextAccessor` like this?
```csharp
public class HttpContextHelper
{
    private IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;

    public HttpContextHelper(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = contextAccessor;
    }
    ...
}

 services.AddSingleton<HttpContextHelper>();
```
And simply inject `HttpContextHelper` where you need it.

Comment: On application startup,
How do I inject? @MohsenEsmailpour

Comment: In order to upgrade the program to .net7, what is the minimum RAM, Cpu, Windows for the client? @PanagiotisKanavos

Comment: It doesn't matter. The client of a web app is the browser. The HTML the web app produces won't change if you move to .NET 6 or .NET 7. On the server, .NET 6 and 7 are each faster and use less memory than the previous version. That said, .NET 7 itself is a single-year, standard support version. If you don't want to upgrade next year, use .NET 6 which is supported until 2024

Answer (score 2):

I saw that you add **IHttpContextAccessor** in service:

```
services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
```

In the code you sent, you got all the requests in the context for a unique consideration (you set is as Singleton), but every request to send the server information was different from the other context, you get it's request.

but I think you should Injected **IHttpContextAccessor** like

```
Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Comment: have you seen the question and the desired code in full? **Because I put this code**

Comment: Yes, You wrong in implementing IHttpContextAccessor service in DI